# Installing Cordova Plugins in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to build a hybrid app using Cordova project in visual studio. I need some plugins to build the app. I follow the post in MSDN [Manage Plugins for Apps Built with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx)

But I get this:
Couldn't download plugins.

[To See This Error's Picture please click this](http://justpaste.it/ii5a)

What steps I am missing or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

open your CMD. cd to your project

```
cd your_project_directory
```

then install the cordova plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I did that it says "Cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: To run Cordova commands on Windows you need to install using CMD.

`npm install -g cordova`

For more information about installing Cordova go to:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: install cordova first before proceed

Answer (score 0):

1. run following command to install cordova globally

   **`npm install -g cordova`**
2. Then create new cordova project using

   **`cordova start project_name`**
3. Go to directory and Install plugin using

   **`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`**
4. Copy Installed plugin folder & paste into plugins folder in Visual Studio solution.
5. Update config file

   **`<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />`**
6. Build the Project